# Why does RTABmap subscribing to my other TF?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have noticed some problem. When I launch RTABmap, it subscribes to my noisy_odom TF and also subscribes to filtered_odom TF and I think it makes my map being messy and sometimes I get this warning:

```
Rtabmap.cpp:2072::process() Rejected loop closure 1 -> 177: Not enough inliers 0/5 (matches=1) between 1 and 177
```

Which I guess means that RTABmap also does the visual odom which I do not want as it messes my map (even though I did not start that node).

So here is my RQT_GRAPH:
[image: image description]

And in SVG format:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yPJPbiR21NL2JgOSYAguKLyQtq43g2SM

My RTAB database if needed:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WcAdEi4AJz7bB0QilmaGtcxCU6EF10tQ/view?usp=sharing

And finally this is how I launch my RTABmap (note that on my remote robot I launch rtabmap/stere_sync and it sends rgbd_image topic):

```
<launch>
    <arg name="use_zed"         default="true"  doc="Set to false when using Intel Realsense D435"/>
    <arg name="localization"    default="false" doc="Localization mode for navigation"/>
    <arg name="database_path"   default="rtabmap.db"/>
    <arg name="rviz"            default="true"/>
    <arg name="rtabmapviz"      default="true" />
    <arg name="rate"            default="1.0"/>

    <arg name="gui_cfg"                 default="~/.ros/rtabmap_gui.ini" />

    <arg     if="$(arg localization)" name="rtabmap_args"  default=""/>
    <arg unless="$(arg localization)" name="rtabmap_args"  default="--delete_db_on_start"/>
    <arg     if="$(arg localization)" name="rviz_config"   default="$(find rtabmap_ros)/config/navigation.rviz"/>
    <arg unless="$(arg localization)" name="rviz_config"   default="$(find rtabmap_ros)/config/mapping.rviz"/>


    <arg name="input_odom"       default="/odom"/>
    <arg     if="$(arg use_zed)" name="input_image"        default="/stereo_camera/left/image_rect_color"/>
    <arg     if="$(arg use_zed)" name="input_depth"        default="/stereo_camera/depth/depth_registered"/>
    <arg     if="$(arg use_zed)" name="input_camera_info"  default="/stereo_camera/left/camera_info"/>

    <arg name="rgb_topic"               default="/rgb/image_rect_color" />
    <arg name="depth_topic"             default="/depth/depth_registered" />
    <arg name="camera_info_topic"       default="/rgb/camera_info" />
    <arg name="rgbd_topic"       default="/rgbd_image" />


    <!-- Rtabmap params -->
    <arg name="subscribe_rgbd" default="true"/>
    <arg name="stereo" default="false"/>
    <arg name="approx_sync" default="true"/>

    <!-- rgbd_sync params -->
    <arg name="compressed"              default="true"/>
    <arg name="rgb_image_transport"     default="compressed"/>
    <arg name="approx_rgbd_sync"        default="true"/>
    <arg name="rgbd_sync"               default="true"/>
    <!-- These arguments should not be modified directly, see referred topics without "_relay" suffix above -->
    <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="rgb_topic_relay"           default="$(arg rgb_topic)_relay"/>
    <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="rgb_topic_relay"           default="$(arg rgb_topic)"/>
    <arg if="$(arg compressed)"     name="depth_topic_relay"         default="$(arg depth_topic)_relay"/>
    <arg unless="$(arg compressed)" name="depth_topic_relay"         default="$(arg depth_topic)"/>
    <arg if="$(arg rgbd_sync)"      name="rgbd_topic_relay"          default="$(arg rgbd_topic)"/>
    <arg unless="$(arg rgbd_sync)"  name="rgbd_topic_relay"          default="$(arg rgbd_topic)_relay"/>

    <!-- launch rgbd_sync -->
    <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_rgb" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="compressed in:=$(arg rgb_topic) raw out:=$(arg rgb_topic_relay)" />
    <node if="$(arg compressed)" name="republish_depth" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" args="compressedDepth in:=$(arg depth_topic) raw out:=$(arg depth_topic_relay)" />
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="rgbd_sync" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/rgbd_sync" output="screen">
        <remap from="rgb/image"       to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
        <remap from="depth/image"     to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
        <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
        <remap from="rgbd_image"      to="$(arg rgbd_topic_relay)"/>
        <param name="approx_sync"     type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_rgbd_sync)"/>
        <param name="queue_size"      type="int"    value="100"/>
        <param name="depth_scale"     type="double" value="1.0"/>
    </node>


    <!-- RTAB=Map node -->
    <group ns="rtabmap">
        <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="$(arg rtabmap_args)">

            <param name="subscribe_scan"     type="bool"     value="false"/>

            <param name="database_path"       type="string" value="$(arg database_path)"/>
            <param name="frame_id"            type="string" value="base_footprint"/>
            <param name="subscribe_rgbd"       type="bool"   value="$(arg subscribe_rgbd)"/>
            <param name="subscribe_stereo"     type="bool"   value="$(arg stereo)"/>
            <param name="subscribe_depth"     type="bool"   value="true"/>
            <param name="subscribe_scan"      type="bool"   value="false"/>
            <param name="approx_sync"          type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>

            <!-- Input topics -->
            <remap from="odom"                to="$(arg input_odom)"/>
            <remap from="rgb/image"       to="$(arg rgb_topic_relay)"/>
            <remap from="depth/image"     to="$(arg depth_topic_relay)"/>
            <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
            <remap from="rgbd_image"      to="$(arg rgbd_topic_relay)"/>

            <!-- Output topics -->
            <remap from="grid_map" to="/map"/>

            <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="100"/>

            <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
            <param name="RGBD/NeighborLinkRefining" type="string" value="true"/>
            <param name="RGBD/ProximityBySpace"     type="string" value="true"/>
            <param name="RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd" type="string" value="false"/>
            <param name="RGBD/AngularUpdate"        type="string" value="0.05"/>
            <param name="RGBD/LinearUpdate"         type="string" value="0.05"/>
            <param name="Optimizer/Slam2D"          type="string" value="true"/>
            <param name="Vis/MinInliers"            type="string" value="5"/>
            <param name="Vis/InlierDistance"        type="string" value="0.1"/>
            <param name="Kp/MaxDepth"               type="string" value="1.75"/>
            <param name="Vis/MaxDepth"              type="string" value="1.75"/>
            <param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr"           type="string" value="700"/>
            <param name="Rtabmap/DetectionRate"     type="string" value="$(arg rate)" />
            <param name="Mem/RehearsalSimilarity"   type="string" value="0.45"/>
            <param name="Grid/MaxObstacleHeight"    type="string" value="1.7" />
            <param name="Grid/NoiseFilteringRadius" type="string" value="0.05"/>
            <param name="Grid/NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors" type="string" value="5"/>
            <param name="Grid/3D" type="bool" value="false"/>
            <param name="Grid/RayTracing" type="bool" value="true"/>

            <!-- Localization mode -->
            <param     if="$(arg localization)" name="Mem/IncrementalMemory" type="string" value="false"/>
            <param unless="$(arg localization)" name="Mem/IncrementalMemory" type="string" value="true"/>
            <param name="Mem/InitWMWithAllNodes" type="string" value="$(arg localization)"/>

        </node>
    </group>

    <!-- Localization node -->
    <include if="$(arg localization)" file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/move_base.launch">
        <arg name="model" value="waffle"/>
        <arg name="odom_topic" value="stereo_camera/odom"/>
    </include>
    <node if="$(arg localization)" pkg="turtlebot3_slam_3d" type="detection_publisher.py"
          name="detection_collector" output="screen"/>

    <!-- RVIZ node -->
    <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(arg rviz_config)" />

    <!-- Rtabviz -->

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320389/why-does-rtabmap-subscribing-to-my-other-tf?/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have already `stereo_sync` publishing `rgbd_image` topic on the robot, don't create another `rgbd_sync` on remote. It seems the cause of the mixing stereo and rgbd images in the database.

rtabmap is configured with input "/odom" for odometry. rtabmap should look up only one TF, what is the `frame_id` set in the `/odom` topic? Is there another node publishing also on the same topic `/odom` but with different TF? If so, it is maybe why you see rtabmap looking for two different frames.

TF between your base frame and camera frame doesn't look right, the camera seems looking down (the camera cloud's ground doesn't match the floor).

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1